# Who could be the Azor Ahai?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

During the seasons of *Game of Thrones* we have heard Melisandre talking about Azor Ahai Reborn, a hero fighting against the Others (White Walkers), we will not find out who this character actually is, but **which characters fit the criteria of Azor Ahai?**

Comment: They claimed for Stannis and Khaleesi but i think Jon Snow will be  Azor Ahai.

Comment: I feel the same thing, but based on what ? and what is realy this Azor Ahai is Capable of?

Comment: http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Azor_Ahai

Comment: Can very well be Danerys seems like only thing show is doing is building her up while chopping others. This question seems to invite speculation though.

Comment: Basically; anyone. But we won't know until it's revealed!

Comment: This seems unanswerable at this point and could potentially devolve into arguing about fan theories. Leaning towards thinking this should be closed. Btw I think it's Daenarys. :)  Light bringer is her dragons, which she acquired due to the blood sacrifice of her husband.

Comment: At this point of time, it is not possible to give exact answer even for book readers. And for tv series, its impossible to answer. Also  question itself asks what do you think means its opinion based question only.

Comment: Updated question to make less opiniony. This question should be re-opened now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Anyone really**

But for now, based on the actual prophecy:

> There will come a day after a long summer when the stars bleed and the cold breath of darkness falls heavy on the world. In this dread hour a warrior shall draw from the fire a burning sword. And that sword shall be Lightbringer, the Red Sword of Heroes, and he who clasps it shall be Azor Ahai come again, and the darkness shall flee before him.<sup>[[1]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Azor_Ahai#Azor_Ahai_come_again)</sup>

And if you believe that **[Azor Ahai Reborn](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Azor_Ahai#Azor_Ahai_come_again)** is the same person as **[The Prince That Was Promised](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Prince_that_was_promised)**:

> When the red star bleeds and the darkness gathers, Azor Ahai shall be born again amidst smoke and salt.<sup>[[2]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_prince_that_was_promised#About)</sup>

You see, the candidate must meet the following [criteria](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_prince_that_was_promised#Signs_of_the_coming_of_the_prince_that_was_promised):

> - The birth of a male child - a prince. (erroneous according to Maester Aemon)
> - The prince is of the blood of the dragon
> - Born of the line of Aerys and Rhaella Targaryen
> - Born amidst smoke
> - Born amidst salt
> - A bleeding star in the skies. (also mentioned is being born beneath a bleeding star)
> - Possibly the return of dragons (when he was a boy, Aegon V Targaryen recalled that King Aerys I read about the return of dragons in a prophecy.)
> - The dark eye falls upon the prince?

Therefore, the closest candidates are:

**[Daenerys Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daenerys_Targaryen)**

- Was born on Dragonstone when a huge storm hit - **Salt**
- Was re-born on the Dothraki Sea in Drogo's Funeral Pyre - **Smoke**
- Returned dragons to the world
- Is of the line of **Aerys** and **Rhaella Targaryen** (their youngest child)
- Is the "blood of the dragon"
- Benerro claims that "The Dark Eye" has befallen her
- [The Bleeding Star](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Red_comet) appears as soon as she "births" her dragons
- Her dragons are said to be her **[Lightbringer](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lightbringer)**

Then there's [*A Dance With Dragons* spoilers]

> **[Jon Snow](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jon_Snow)**
>
> - Rumoured to have been conceived of Rhaegar Targaryen and Lyanna Stark<sup>[[3]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jon_Snow/Theories#Lyanna_Stark)</sup> - of the line of **Aerys** and therfore is **blood of the dragon**
> - When he gets stabbed, his blood "smokes" and Bowen Marsh is crying - **Salt** and **Smoke**
> - Bleeding Star appears when he is "born" into the Night's Watch
> - Theorised that he will "wake dragons from stone"
> - Dark Eye can also be another reference to The Great Other (who clearly has his eyes on Jon)
> - His **[Lightbringer](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lightbringer)** could be Longclaw, or the Night's Watch or even Ghost

and finally,

> **[Aegon VI Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen_(son_of_Rhaegar))**
>
> - Eldest son of Rhaegar and Elia Martell - therefore he is of the line of **Aerys** and **Rhaella** and is **blood of the dragon**
> - That's it

If you don't necessarily believe that **Azor Ahai Reborn** is the same person as **The Prince That Was Promised**:

**Stannis Baratheon**
Melisandre is convinced that AAR is in fact our very own Stannis The Mannis!

> **Jon Snow**
>
> - Consider this line from Melisandre's very own POV chapter:
> - "I pray for a glimpse of Azor Ahai, and R'hllor shows me only Snow."<sup>*-A Song of Ice and Fire: Book Five - A Dance With Dragons, Chapter Thirty-One ([Melisandre I](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Dance_with_Dragons-Chapter_31)).*</sup>
> - Snow, in this case is widely believed to refer to Jon Snow (the capitalisation of the "S" is on purpose)!
> - Further to this, there's some more evidence based on the [Origin of the name Azor Ahai](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/92690/21267)

**All of this can change based on the show-writers (David Benioff and D.B. Weiss) or the author of the books (George R. R. Martin) at any point; and we won't find out the final outcome until the very end!**

Comment: Not Jon Snow I guess, any more.

Comment: People are getting brought back to life like flies in GoT, so no biggy!

Answer (score 2):

There are few candidates who qualify to be named as one of the favorites to become Azor Ahai.

> 1 Stannis Baratheon
>
> 2 Daenerys Targaryen
>
> 3 Jon Snow
>
> 4 Victarion Greyjoy (**Hasn't appeared on TV**)
>
> 5 Aegon Targaryen (**Hasn't appeared on TV**)

Please refer to **[Azor Ahai/Theories](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Azor_Ahai/Theories)** page for information on why fans believe these are the candidates.

**Currently there isn't enough information to determine who would it actually be.**

Comment: And of course there's the possibility that the legend and prophecies have been sorely misunderstood... wouldn't be the first time :-)

Comment: Even that can be true. Thats the thing with prophecies, right now we can't be even sure  Azor Ahai and the prince that was promised are the same prophecy.

Comment: Who is Victarion Greyjoyand how is he qualified ?

Comment: @AnkitSharma He is Theon Greyjoy's uncle.  Check out the link it has sufficient information.